# Regex to match date range as (XXXX–XXXX) or (X) (XXXX–XXXX), brackets included

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
$title = preg_replace('/[\"\*\/\:\<\>\?\|]+/', '', html_entity_decode($title[1], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"));
```

in details only this part is relevant

```
'/[\"\*\/\:\<\>\?\|]+/'
```

I try to edit my regex to match also this text

```
Alfa Beta (1930–2020) 
Alfa beta (I) (1922–2019)
Alfa beta (I)(1922–2019)
```

Any idea? I want to include brackets as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches your examples:

```
(?:\(.\))?\h*\(\d+–\d+\)
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MvlnPY/1)